# Is high Extent Fragmentation a problem?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, fragmentation, query-performance

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning 'MyTable' table...
Table: 'MyTable' (2048062382); index ID: 1, database ID: 28
TABLE level scan performed.
- Pages Scanned................................: 1019182
- Extents Scanned..............................: 127400
- Extent Switches..............................: 127399
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 8.0
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 100.00% [127398:127400]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 0.01%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 77.25%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 135.7
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 98.32%
```

I have read that Scan Density = 100% is very good, and Logical Scan Fragementation <1% is also great.  77% Extent Scan Fragmentation troubles me, but the internet says to ignore it.

I'm analyzing a single-table slow performing query.  It runs ~30 seconds on first execution, then 200 ms on second and subsequent executions.  I can reset this behavior with `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`.

Is the high Extent Scan Fragmentation an important clue?

(If not, I'll likely add another question about my single-table query).

Comment: @Kin SqlServer2012. 34,530,707 rows, 8,153,456 KB data.

Comment: @Marian Query uses a simple "where ParentId in (list of 75 parameters)", and very normal looking "ConstantScan->NestedLoop->IndexSeek->NestedLoop->KeyLookup plan, which is working for other tables, but not this one on this day and on this test site. Returns ~7k rows. I'll put more details in a fresh question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, even if you're doing full table scans, it is unlikely that extent fragmentation will affect performance much, and for more typical query patterns it should be negligible at best. That is for queries that use cached data that fits into memory - obviously fragmentation of any kind becomes rather moot if the data is in memory and isn't being read directly off disk.

Now, you've got a table that is > 8 GB, so it is possible that extent fragmentation might be harmful to your queries. If this query is using a table scan across 34 million rows, and the worst you're getting (on first execution only!) is 30 seconds, then it is extremely unlikely that lowering that extent fragmentation number is going to help much. That 30 seconds is spent loading the data into memory, and I can't fathom that improving the extent fragmentation will buy you much there. If you have the memory to spare to keep this table in memory, perhaps you should consider a startup job or some background process that periodically runs the query without forcing a user to wait for it, ensuring that it stays fresh in the cache.

Hekaton might be for you.

Answer (score 4):

> ConstantScan->NestedLoop->IndexSeek->NestedLoop->KeyLookup plan

This plan didn't access the whole table since it returned only 7,000 rows out of 34.5M rows.

The total amount of data coming off disk is miniscule compared to the size of the entire table<sup>1</sup>; random seek time to fulfill the key lookup operations seems to dominate. Fixing fragmentation issues only apply when *scan* operations are involved. Once the access pattern is random like it appears to be here, fragmentation -- and fragmentation metrics -- are irrelevant.

You should be able to verify what's going on by watching the disk activity in Performance Monitor or Resource Monitor while the query is running -- I expect you'll see very low disk throughput.

Assuming my analysis is correct, here are a couple of suggestions (which can be combined) to improve the query execution time, particularly with a cold cache:

- Put the data file(s) on a storage subsystem that can better handle random reads. As a rough estimate, 30s / 7,000 rows is ~4ms average seek time, which is not bad, so this could be an expensive proposition.
- Modify the nonclustered index to cover the query by using `INCLUDE` columns, thereby eliminating the need for key lookups, and hence most of the random disk activity. This is likely the best solution, even if you sacrifice a bit of extra storage space for it. Hopefully the table isn't super wide.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Assuming approximately equal row sizes.</sub>

---

Also, as an aside, [`DBCC SHOWCONTIG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx) has been deprecated for quite a while -- the replacement going forward is [`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx).